# Why doesn't the link in my answer work?

Tags: support, hyperlinks

In my answer to [How to use indexOf (int ch) in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12335268/how-to-use-indexof-int-ch-in-java/12335440#12335440) I have a link to the String.indexOf(int, int) method in the Java API docs which isn't working correctly. The URL is correct. I suspect that the problem is that the URL has a space in it. How do I fix this?

Comment: Works for me....

Comment: @KDiTraglia I guess I should clarify. Three of the links work fine. There's a fourth link that doesn't work. At least on my end, it shows the description and URL in the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason was indeed the space in the URL. Replacing that with `%20` made it work.

Comment: I just saw your edit. Thanks!