# What is the correct way to ask for formatting and/or editing help?

Tags: discussion, edits

Occasionally, I don't know how to format something in my question or answer on SO. How do I ask for editing assistance? In one case, I [asked here on meta.so](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146380/why-doesnt-the-link-in-my-answer-work) and the question was justifiably closed as *Too Localized*. Is there some other, more acceptable way to ask for help editing a post?

Comment: Read the FAQs - most of what you need to know will be there. If the case is complicated, then you can post a question and ask. Check existing questions when you are posting the new question (via the title hint).

Comment: Have you looked at the [Formatting Sandbox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3122/21960)?

Comment: @ValetTree: Formatting Sandbox is also a good place to test and to learn from existing formatting, but it is a sandbox, so things are not very organized. The question makes quite a good example, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason the question has been closed has nothing to do with how the question has been written; it just means the question has been thought not be helpful for future readers.

What you are describing is expected because, as said in [Is a URL allowed to contain a space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/497908/are-urls-allowed-to-have-a-space-in-them)

> The space character is unsafe because significant spaces may disappear and insignificant spaces may be introduced when URLs are transcribed or typeset or subjected to the treatment of word-processing programs.
>   All unsafe characters must always be encoded within a URL.

Comment: Exactly; Once you got your answer, the usefulness of the question was ended, so don't worry about it. Any good-faith question that you ask here which is about the network or how to use it, and which isn't a duplicate of others, is usually just fine.

Comment: @Andrew So asking this kind of question on meta is okay? It just gets closed once it is answered?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on why my question was closed. I took it to mean that the question wasn't appropriate for meta.so.

Comment: @Code-Guru If it were not appropriate, it would be closed as off-topic. It is just preferable to ask questions that are useful to other users too. For example, if I ask a question to merge two accounts of mine because one account was created by mistake, that question would be closed as too localized, as nobody but me is interested in my request to merge my accounts.